# XSLT Apply Templates where child element starts with 'A'

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have an xml structure, basically as follows:

```
<Export>
<TaskWords>
    <TaskWord>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <WordType>A01</WordType>
        <Body>blah</body>
    </TaskWord>
    <TaskWord>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <WordType>A02</WordType>
        <Body>blah</body>
    </TaskWord>
    <TaskWord>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <WordType>B01</WordType>
        <Body>blah</body>
    </TaskWord>
    <TaskWord>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <WordType>B02</WordType>
        <Body>blah</body>
    </TaskWord>
</TaskWords>
</Export>
```

I also have some XSLT code which applies a template that builds an XHTML table of the TaskWords, grouped by WordType.

I want to apply the template to a subset of TaskWords, where for example WordType starts with 'A'; This is so that I can drop all the 'A' WordTypes into one table of a report, then add some more content from elsewhere, then follow up with a table of all the 'B' WordTypes.

I've been trying calls along the following lines to no avail:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="TaskWords[TaskWord/WordType[starts-with(.,'A')]]"/> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="OtherContent"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="TaskWords[TaskWord/WordType[starts-with(.,'B')]]"/>
```

Am I on the right path, in trying to filter down the sets of TaskWords using the select statement of the apply-templates command? Any advice, pointers or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd post a [mcve] so that we could reproduce the error (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- identity template - copies on no-match -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/Export/TaskWords"> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <TABLE_A>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="TaskWord[starts-with(WordType,'A')]"/> 
            </TABLE_A>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="OtherContent"/>    <!-- Apply the rest -->
            <TABLE_B>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="TaskWord[starts-with(WordType,'B')]"/> 
            </TABLE_B>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<Export>
    <TaskWords>
        <TABLE_A><TaskWord>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <WordType>A01</WordType>
                <Body>blah</Body>
            </TaskWord>
            <TaskWord>
                <ID>2</ID>
                <WordType>A02</WordType>
                <Body>blah</Body>
            </TaskWord>
        </TABLE_A>
        <TABLE_B><TaskWord>
                <ID>3</ID>
                <WordType>B01</WordType>
                <Body>blah</Body>
            </TaskWord>
            <TaskWord>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <WordType>B02</WordType>
                <Body>blah</Body>
            </TaskWord>
        </TABLE_B>
    </TaskWords>
</Export>
```

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow, looks promising. Even looks close to something I already tried, other than the xsl:copy commands, which I neglected to include. Hopefully they'll solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Look into xsl:for-each-group. By setting the appropriate attributes, you can get distinct groups where all members of the group have the condition you are looking. Then you can do processing at the whole group level, or for each member of the group depending on what your output requirements are.

Comment: I'm using for-each-group already to build the table of TaskWords, but all my raw data is in elements rather than attributes, so I'm struggling to filter to distinct groups within the loop itself. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TaskWords">
        <xsl:copy>
            <table_A>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="TaskWord[WordType[starts-with(.,'A')]]"/>
                </table_A>
            <table_B>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="TaskWord[WordType[starts-with(.,'B')]]"/>
            </table_B>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

For others, the solution I went with was along the following lines...

```
<xsl:template match="/Export/TaskWords">            
        <table width="100%">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="TaskWord[starts-with(WordType,'A')]" group-by="WordType">
                <tr class="noborder">
                    <th colspan="2"><h2><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></h2></th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Export/TaskContents"/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Export/Outputs"/>

        <table width="100%">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="TaskWord[starts-with(WordType,'B')]" group-by="WordType">
                <tr class="noborder">
                    <th colspan="2"><h2><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></h2></th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TaskWord">
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:if test="Status='P'">
            <tr>
                <td class="leftcol"><h3><xsl:value-of select="PimID" /></h3></td>
                <td><p><xsl:value-of select="Description" /></p></td>
            </tr> 
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I didn't bother with any of the identity transform as I don't want to bring through any of the remaining nodes, or bring through standard xml schema elements, as I'm just constructing XHTML string reports.